# How to search in an array by value part

Tags: php, arrays, function, class, foreach

I want to get data from api request. I make a query on the value of oc52. Get $date array. The issuing server adds the MH prefix. Which generates itself relative to the name. I am trying to extract part of the array using the class.

This is the array I get when querying:

```
$data = [
    [
        'product' => 'CH C104.12',
        'brand' => 'CH C104.12',
        'price' => 12.34,
    ],
    [
        'product' => 'MH OC52',
        'brand' => 'MH OC52',
        'price' => 56.78,
    ],
    [
        'product' => 'WX WL7074-12',
        'brand' => 'WX WL7074-12',
        'price' => 90.12,
    ],
];
```

Here's the class I'm doing a search for

```
class ProductFilterIterator extends \FilterIterator
{
     protected $filter;

     public function __construct(\Iterator $iterator,  $filter)
     {
         $this->filter = $filter;
         parent::__construct($iterator);
     }

     public function accept() : bool
     {
         $current = $this->getInnerIterator()->current();
         return $current['product'] == $this->filter;

     }
}

$iterator = (new \ArrayObject($data))->getIterator();
$filter1 = new ProductFilterIterator($iterator, 'OC52');

foreach ($filter1 as $data) {
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($data);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Does nothing reflect? If I write in line MH OC52:

```
$filter1 = new ProductFilterIterator($iterator, 'MH OC52');
```

Then everything works.
How do I implement it if I don't know the front - MH ???

Comment: Just to check - is it just a case of checking the string ends with the value (for example OC52),

Comment: How do I find MH and line up :`code` $filter1 = new ProductFilterIterator($iterator, 'MH OC52');? `code`

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to check the end of the string, this stores the length to check after storing the filter.  Then in the main `accept()` method, it just looks at the last part of the string (using `substr()`) in the array to compare...

```
class ProductFilterIterator extends \FilterIterator
{
    protected $filter;
    protected $length;

    public function __construct(\Iterator $iterator,  $filter)
    {
        $this->filter = $filter;
        $this->length = -strlen($filter);
        parent::__construct($iterator);
    }

    public function accept() : bool
    {
        $current = $this->getInnerIterator()->current();
        return substr($current['product'], $this->length) == $this->filter;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error- Fatal error: Cannot declare class ProductFilterIterator, because the name is already in use in